# Pandas Match and unmatch on differnt columns in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to perform a self join on a dataframe where the resultant data should be match on 2 columns and mismatch on another column.

```
ID  NAME    POST_CODE  UPDATE_DATE 
1   David   45678    20/12/2012 
1   David   50010    20/12/2012 
2   Peter   23234    12/12/2014 
3   Venk    12122    05/10/2018 
4   Mark    23232    03/05/2017 
5   Harry   15785    03/04/2015 
5   Harry   89897    01/04/2019
```

My resultant output should be [Here I want latest Post Code from each ID, even if the ID got 2 different Post Code]

```
ID  NAME    POST_CODE  UPDATE_DATE
1   David   45678    20/12/2012 
1   David   50010    20/12/2012
```

If it's SQL I will use this query.

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.ID, A.NAME, A.POST_CODE, A.UPDATE_DATE
FROM TABLE A 
inner join (SELECT A.ID, A.NAME, A.POST_CODE, A.UPDATE_DATE FROM TABLE) as B 
ON A.ID = B.ID and A.POST_CODE <> B.POST_CODE and A.UPDATE_DATE  = B.UPDATE_DATE
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `pandas` we can use `filter`

```
df.groupby(['ID','NAME','UPDATE_DATE']).filter(lambda x : x['POST_CODE'].nunique()!=1 )
   ID   NAME  POST_CODE UPDATE_DATE
0   1  David      45678  20/12/2012
1   1  David      50010  20/12/2012
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response WeNYoBen, your code does the purpose but I am seeing some mismatch with my SQL result and Python result.

Comment: It worked, I have just made a small change based on my requirement to consider unique > 1 as earlier !=1 caused some additional values. `df2.groupby(['ID','UPDATE_DATE']).filter(lambda x : x['POST_CODE'].nunique()>1 )`

Answer (score 1):

You can keep duplicated subsets of `ID` and `UPDATE_DATE` then drop all rows of duplicate `POST_CODE`.

```
df[df.duplicated(subset=['ID', 'UPDATE_DATE'], keep=False)].drop_duplicates(subset=['POST_CODE'], keep=False)

   ID   NAME  POST_CODE UPDATE_DATE
0   1  David      45678  20/12/2012
1   1  David      50010  20/12/2012
```

Answer (score 0):

you can doe it similarly how you do it in sql using merge

```py
## get only rows with duplicated ID and UPDATE_DATE
df2 = df[df["UPDATE_DATE"].duplicated(keep=False)]

## do inner join and take columns of 1st table only then drop duplicates
df2.merge(df2, on=["ID", "UPDATE_DATE"], how="inner", suffixes=["", "_2"]).iloc[:,:-2].drop_duplicates()
```